# List description of a package list

Tags: shell-script, dpkg

I'm writing a `bash` script,
and I have a list of `dpkg` package names and I want my script to write a text file with the following format:

```
name of package

description

name of package

description

...
```

Here is the simple sentence that should do it but it does not...

```
cat /media/sdcard/liste_des_paquets_sans_dependances_inverse | while  read ligne ; do
dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n\n${Description}\n\n\n\n' --show $ligne >> descriptions.txt
done
```

Maybe you'll see where my fault is?

Comment: and what id the `/media/sdcard/liste_des_paquets_sans_dependances_inverse` content?

Comment: The `/liste_des_paquets_sans_dependances_inverse` is a list with a package name at each line
EDIT: the terminal answers me: `dpkg-query: no packages found matching xinput` (for each package of the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found the problem.
It was the "end of line" character in the list.
i did a "return" press on each beginning of line and an "enter" press to change this "end of line" character and it worked...
just a few things that take several hours of your time... i'll work on a different script to make my list...
thank you both for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample script:

```
for i in $(cat /media/sdcard/liste_des_paquets_sans_dependances_inverse) 
do 
dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n\n${Description}\n\n\n\n' --show $i >> description.txt 
done
```

Comment: the answer is the same: `dpkg-query: no packages found matching xinput`
i do not understand because this list has been made with a script that list packages that don't have reverse dependencies, so they are installed on my system... And the list in `liste_des_paquets_sans_dependances_inverse` is exactly the same type of list i use in other scripts with some other commands...
And even when i try to do the command manually for one package it works... it boils my brain...

Comment: run `apt-get update`

Comment: done... same result...

Comment: The problem come from your list , there are some package that isn't installed on your system. you can try it with a small list {apt , dpkg and aptitude}

Comment: well you're right... but the thing is all the packages in the list are actually installed on my system... i'll try to work on the list and see if i can find where is my error...